# set a field in document - mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to set a field in a document in mongoDB but I'm getting the following error when I run `node app.js`

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

theres my code:

```
app.get('/verify', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.protocol + ":/" + req.get('host'));
    var collection = "usuarios";
    collectionDriver.getCollection(collection, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(400, error);
        } else
            the_collection.update("{_id:" + req.query.id + "}, {$set: {ativo:'T'}}");
    });
});
```

EDIT:

```
    app.get('/verify',function(req,res){
console.log(req.protocol+":/"+req.get('host'));
   var collection = "usuarios";
   collectionDriver.getCollection(collection, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) { res.send(400, error);}
        else  
          the_collection.update({ '_id': req.query.id, $set: { ativo: 'T' } });
        //  the_collection.update("{_id:'"+req.query.id+"'}, {$set: {ativo:'T'}}");}
   });


});
```

and the error

`events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ladessa/files/MelhoraCidade/server/app.js:206:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)`

Comment: Can you show the complete error traceback?

Comment: Looks like the port in which you are starting the server is already opened by another process.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes...I kill the process and run again and its run...but my verify function doesn't update my field...

Answer (score 2):

As per [mongoose's `update` documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html), the `update` method should be called with a minimum of two parameters. Quoting the function signature,

> ```
> Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
> ```

1. `conditions` - A valid JavaScript object to find the actual documents to be updated.
2. `update` - The actual updatation object, this determines the actual change made in the documents.

**Note** In case, you are using native mongodb driver, the `update` function accepts similar parameters. Quoting the [`update`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#update) documentation,

> ```
> update(selector, document, options, callback)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `selector` The selector for the update operation.
>
> `document` The update document.

So, your function has to be changed like this

```
the_collection.update({
    '_id': req.query.id
}, {
    $set: {
        ativo: 'T'
    }
});
```